# Cosmos Write Returning 429 Error With Bulk Execution

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a solution utilizing a micro-service approach. One of our micro-service is responsible for pushing data to Cosmos. Our Cosmos database is using serverless provision having a 5,000 RU/s limit.

The data we are inserting into Cosmos looks like the below. There are 10 columns and we are pushing a batch containing 5,807 rows of this data.

| Id | CompKey | Primary Id | Secondary Id | Type | DateTime | Item | Volume | Price | Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Veg_Buy | csd2354csd | dfg564dsfg55 | Buy | 30/08/21 | Leek | 10 | 0.75 | 5.00 |
| 2 | Veg_Buy | sdf15s1dfd | sdf31sdf654v | Buy | 30/08/21 | Corn | 5 | 0.48 | 3.00 |

We are retrieving data from multiple sources, normalizing it, and sending out the data as one bulk execution to Cosmos. The retrieval process happens every hour. We understand that we are spiking the Cosmos database once per hour with the data that has been retrieved and then stop sending data until the next retrieval cycle. So if this high peak is the problem, what remedies exist for such a scenario?

Can anyone shed some light on what we should/need to do to overcome this issue? Perhaps we are missing a setting when creating the Cosmos database or possibly this has something to do with partitioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mostly determine these things by looking at the metrics published in the Azure Portal. This doc is a good place to start, [Monitor and debug with insights in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics).

In particular I would look at the section titled, **Determine the throughput consumption by a partition key range**

If you are not dealing with a hot partition key you may want to look at options to throttle your writes. This may include modifying your batch size and putting the write operations on a while..loop with a one second timer until RU/s consumed equals 5000 RU/s. You could also possibly look at doing queue-based load leveling and put writes on a queue in front of Cosmos and stream them in.

Comment: Can you please explain how a hot partition is created and how it is affected by the number of RU/s available?

Comment: A hot partition occurs when data is written to a single or small number of partition key values in a container. A classic example is a system that is partitioned by date. New data tends to have a date value for today's date. If you try to ingest a large amount of data with the date property all with the current day's date you will quickly exhaust the provisioned throughput for a container. Keep in mind that throughput for a container is distributed equally across all physical partitions for that container. So for write heavy scenarios data needs to be distributed across a range of pk values.

Comment: There are a ton of articles on partitioning in Cosmos. Here's a good place to start, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview. Here is also a good article to start with, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/modeling-data

Comment: Thanks for sharing these links. I have gone through them and I have better understood the notion of hot partitioning now. Now we better understand our problem. In essence what we have is a data collection service picking up data from various third party endpoints. We have a partition key comprising of the following "<ClientName>_<ThirdPartyName>_<Date>".

Comment: The problem is that we are picking up data continuously every hour, resulting in all the data having the same partition key, thus causing a hot partition. We now see that when we structured the partition key, we made it to be optimized for reads and not for writes. We understand that it is somewhat impossible to have a partition key catering for both reads and writes. Any ideas as to how we might at least create a partition key that won't result in all data having the same partition?

Comment: In scenarios where you have to optimize for both, use Change Feed and copy the data from the write optimized container to a read optimized container that you use to serve queries from.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I have marked this as the correct answer!

Comment: @RyanFalzon did changing partition key actually help ? Maybe I'm mistaken but this would only matter if there would be bigger number of physical partitions not logical partitions where a new physical partition is created when exceeding 10 gb of data